# IE8 and 9 not supporting DOM. Can't find answer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I am running a DOM script and it is working PERFECTLY in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE8 or 9. The error messages in IE that I get are

- `document.getElementByld(..)` is null or not an object
- Object doesn't support this property or method
- Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined (URL: http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js)

Code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // DOM Ready    
    $(function() {


        $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/LaunchSeven.json?count=2&callback=?', function(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, item){
                $('#twitter').append('<div class="tweet"><p>' + item.text.linkify() + '</p><p><strong>' + relative_time(item.created_at) + '</strong></p></div>');
            });

        });



        function relative_time(time_value) {
          var values = time_value.split(" ");
          time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
          var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
          var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
          var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
          delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);

          var r = '';
          if (delta < 60) {
            r = 'a minute ago';
          } else if(delta < 120) {
            r = 'couple of minutes ago';
          } else if(delta < (45*60)) {
            r = (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + ' minutes ago';
          } else if(delta < (90*60)) {
            r = 'an hour ago';
          } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
            r = '' + (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + ' hours ago';
          } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
            r = '1 day ago';
          } else {
            r = (parseInt(delta / 86400)).toString() + ' days ago';
          }

          return r;
        }

        String.prototype.linkify = function() {
            return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+/, function(m) {
                return m.link(m);
            });
        };   


    });


</script>
```

---

Thank you in Advance,

Adam

Comment: snap comment ... check out modernizr:  http://modernizr.com/

Comment: You need to tell us what line of code is generating the above errors so we can trace which variables have the problem.  I don't see `getElementById` or `innerHTML` in the code you've provided.

Comment: Hi jfriend00, I got that error fixed thanks to "am not i am". Now I am getting a message on Line 17. It says Object doesn't support this property or method. The only thing on Line 17 is });

Comment: Then it says on Line 9 "Object expected". Line 9 would be   $(function() {

Answer (score 1):

Your page needs to have an element with the ID `twitter_update_list`...

```
document.getElementById('twitter_update_list').innerHTML = statusHTML.join('');
```

Can't say why it isn't available in IE without seeing more code.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed one of my Scripting Errors. Now I have an error that says Line 17, Object doesn't support this property or method. Line 17 would be });

Comment: This is the code right above that, including line 17.        $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/LaunchSeven.json?count=2&callback=?', function(data){
       $.each(data, function(index, item){
        $('#twitter_update_list').append('<div class="tweet"><p>' + item.text.linkify() + '</p><p><strong>' + relative_time(item.created_at) + '</strong></p></div>');
       });
      
      });

Comment: I'm guessing item.text is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Second argument. That's a function definition and not a function being fired. but if m.link(m) didn't work by itself, executing the function properly wouldn't work either.

```
    String.prototype.linkify = function() {
        return this.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+/, function(m) {
            return m.link(m);
        });
    };
```

So just make the second arg `m.link(m)` (no semi)

I'm not sure this explains your document.getElementById issue though. But it might be causing a bug cascade somewhere.

Also, you should really define that string prototype before everything else. I believe only named functions hoist e.g. function someName(){.. vs. var someName = function(){...